# How to show the nonlinear Schrodinger equation is $S^1$-symmetry?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, symmetry

In [**Stability of semiclassical bound states of nonlinear Schrödinger equations with potentials**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01218621), the author say the nonlinear Schrodinger equation 
$$
ih\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = -\frac{h^2}{2}\Delta \psi + V\psi-|\psi|^{p-1}\psi
$$
is $S^1$-symmetry. How to show it ?  In fact, I don't know how to structure the  transformation of $S^1$-symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case we view the group $S^1$ as the unit circle in the complex plane with the group law being complex multiplication.  The symmetry in question is not very sophisticated.  It simply says that if $\psi$ solves
$$
ih\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = -\frac{h^2}{2}\Delta \psi + V\psi-|\psi|^{p-1}\psi
$$
and $e^{i \omega} \in S^1$, then the new function $\phi = e^{i \omega} \psi$ solves
$$
ih\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = -\frac{h^2}{2}\Delta \phi + V\phi-|\phi|^{p-1}\phi.
$$
This follows by multiplying the PDE for $\psi$ by the complex constant $e^{i \omega}$ and noting that $|\psi| = |e^{i\omega} \psi| = |\phi|$.

Comment: Thanks, $|\psi| = |e^{i\omega} \psi| $ is important.